# how can i display the username PHP

Tags: php, session, dreamweaver

I have this code, pls help me to resolve my problem

```
 <?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

what i can do to display the name of user. something like this:

> Hi jo, u are connected

.

The problem, i don't know the value of the name. 
I use `Dreamweaver`.
In the table, i have name for the name.

edit: 
to log in, the member has to put his phone number and password. 
But me i want to display the name of member instead of his number call.

Comment: `echo 'Hi, ' . $_SESSION['MM_Username'];`

Comment: Sorry, but `u are` cannot be justified... -1 just for that...

Comment: @MarcB: Yeah, should be `u r`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Hi " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'].", u are connected.";
```

if user name have at first user phone number like 123456robert and U want to remove the number will do like this

```
$string=str_split($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
$num=count($string);
$username="";
for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
  if(!isnumric($string[$i]))
  {
    for($k=$i;$k<=$num;$k++)
    {
      $username.=$string[$i];
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't get it please write example

Comment: To connect, the member must put the phone number and password.
so MM_Username will display the phone number.

In the table i have:
phone_number for the phone number
pswd for the password
name for the first name
name2 for the last name. 
me i want to display the name.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've set the session variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
```

Put an actual string where it says NULL and it will echo it out when you just go echo $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

Answer (score 0):

I think that i must use something like this:

> $sql = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM members WHERE phonenumber=\'' .
>   $_SESSION['MM_Username']. '\'');   $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
>   echo stripslashes($data['name']);

But i don't know how to do it.